# Messenger Hubs : How do they do it?

Tags: android

I was wondering how is it possible to create messenger hubs like [BlackBerry Hub](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.blackberry.hub) and [Disa](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.disa&hl=en) as they consolidates Facebook Messenger's messages, WhatsApp messages and many other messenger's messages in the single App.

They all are third-party apps and there's no open APIs available for it.  And yet they are on App store. So it must be some ethical way to doing it. I have digged stackoverflow out but couldn't find a satisfactory answer.

Please note that I'm not expecting code blocks here. Any effort will be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding FB:

> To make Facebook Chat available everywhere, we are using the
>   technology Jabber (XMPP), an open messaging protocol supported by most
>   instant messaging software, including iChat, Pidgin, Adium, Miranda
>   and more.

Taken [here](https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook/facebook-chat-now-available-everywhere/297991732130/).

I assume there may be similar possibilities for other applications you need to integrate. Looks like WhatsApp basically uses XMPP too, probably with minor differences. There is a  [tool](https://github.com/stv0g/transwhat) for interconnecting it with plain XMPP.